# 'No such file or directory', but can 'stat' the file

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am able to `stat` a file or see it with `ls`, but any other command fails to read the file:

```
edcc@dev3:~$ stat /var/www/ihec/tracks/Blueprint/hg19/56880.Blueprint.ERS487362.H3K4me3.signal_unstranded.bigWig
  File: '/var/www/ihec/tracks/Blueprint/hg19/56880.Blueprint.ERS487362.H3K4me3.signal_unstranded.bigWig' -> '/home/genomicdata/ihec_datasets/2017-10/wp10/hg19/0e1deb1cb52cf13a3663f163f9ac6285'
  Size: 82          Blocks: 1          IO Block: 512    symbolic link
Device: 917ah/37242d    Inode: 208798      Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1003/    edcc)   Gid: ( 1003/    edcc)
Access: 2017-11-15 12:43:13.802444330 -0500
Modify: 2017-10-18 14:03:37.711749034 -0400
Change: 2017-10-18 14:03:37.711749034 -0400
 Birth: -

edcc@dev3:~$ cat /var/www/ihec/tracks/Blueprint/hg19/56880.Blueprint.ERS487362.H3K4me3.signal_unstranded.bigWig
cat: /var/www/ihec/tracks/Blueprint/hg19/56880.Blueprint.ERS487362.H3K4me3.signal_unstranded.bigWig: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: That isn't a file. It's a symbolic link, and its target doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's a symlink pointing to an unexistent file.